# Why : ‎ ‎$\{A,\emptyset\}$ and $\{A\}$ haven't the same meaning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

According to the definition of [empty set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EmptySet.html) that is the set containing no elements, commonly denoted emptyset or emptyset , Really i'm confused the empty set is nothing and hasn't any element and it is used widely in mathematics especially topology and algebra group , Now my question here is :

> > **Question:** let $A$ be a set of elements and ${\emptyset}‎$ is empty set , Why  : ‎ ‎$\{A,\emptyset\}\ and \{A\}$ haven't  the same meaning ?

**Not:** if they have the same meaning then why should be cite the empty set as a condition in the definition of topological space .

Comment: The fist of those two sets has two elements, the second one has one element. They "don't have the same meaning".

Comment: Typically I'm against using real world examples to explain mathematics, specially something like set theory. But here it is anyway. Suppose you have two boxes, box $A$ has some stuff, box $\varnothing$ is empty. Is holding both boxes the same as holding just box $A$?

Comment: What you have si a set: $\{A,\emptyset\}$, the set that contains two sets, $A$ and $\emptyset$ not $\{A \cup \emptyset\}$

Comment: @GitGud, your example convinced me , i taught Empty set that is nothing as the meaning of 0 as a number

Comment: "i'm confused the empty set is nothing"  The empty set is not nothing.  The empty set is a set that has nothing in it.   A notebook with nothing written in it is not nothing, it is a notebook.  A drawer with a can opener in it is not a can opener.  It *has* a can opener in it but it is not a can opener itself.  A set is not the same thing as the things inside it. An empty set is a thing-- a thing that has nothing in it. So {A, $\emptyset$} is a set with two things in it.  One thing is A.  The other is the emptyset. {A} is a set with one thing in it.  The thing is A. The empty set is not in it.

Comment: Thanks now, but you should know that there are many people has a bad mind as me they taught that empty set is nothing and now i can si that is one "of wrong bielive in mathematics"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they have not: the set $\{A,\varnothing\}$ has two elements unless  $A=\varnothing$, whereas the sets  $\{A\}$ and $\{\varnothing\}$  have one.

In particular, if $A=\{\varnothing\}$, the set $\;\{\{\varnothing\},\varnothing\}$ has two elements – this is even *von Neumann*'s definition of the number $2$.

Answer (score 5):

$\{ A , \emptyset \}$ does not mean $A \cup \emptyset$.

$\{ A , \emptyset \}$ is the set containing the two elements $a,b$, namely $a = A$ and $b = \emptyset$.

$\{A\}$ does not mean $A$, it means the set containing $A$ as an element.

It could also happen that $A =\emptyset$, in which case $\{A, \emptyset\} = \{A\} = \{\emptyset\}$, and the two sets have the same meaning.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is not the empty set, then the meaning is different because $\varnothing\in\{A,\varnothing\}$ is true and $\varnothing \in \{A\}$ is false. Sets are *by definition* different when there's something that is an element of one but not of the other.

If $A$ *is* the empty set, then $\{A,\varnothing\}$ and $\{A\}$ are the same; they are then just different ways to write the set also known as $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: well , pleas read the not that i wrote below of the question , then if they are both the same why should cite empty set in the definition of topological space since it's trivial satisfied ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I do not understand what you're trying to ask there.

Comment: In my mind every non -empty set contain empty set

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: The answer says they are _not_ the same.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Every set has the empty set **as a subset**. Most sets that you meet in practice do not have the empty set **as an element**. Being an element is something completely different from being a subset. It is regrettable and confusing that the word "contains" is being used for both of these; it is best to avoid the word "contains" completely until you are completely sure how sets work.

Answer (score 0):

Babar, Haitha, Tantor and Pink Honk-Honk are four elephants.

A = $\{$Babar, Haitha, Tantor, Pink Honk-honk$\}$.

A is one thing.  It is a set that contains four elephants.  But A is not an elephant.  A is not even four elephants really.  It is a *collection* of four elephants.

A has four things *in* it.  But A, itself, is one thing.

B = {A}={{Babar, Haitha, Tantor, Pink Honk-honk}} has one thing in it.  It has a *set* in it.  It does not have four elephants in it.  It is a set with only one thing in it.  That thing is a set.  (B has something inside it that has four elephants but B, itself, does not have any elephants directly inside it.)

{A} $\ne $ A.

$\emptyset = \{\}$ is set with nothing in it.  It *is* something.  It is a set.  It is a set with nothing in it.

{A} is a set with one thing in it.  {A, $\emptyset$} is a set with with *two* things in it.

{A} $\ne $ {A, $\emptyset$} because the two sets have different things inside them.

===

Note:  $A \cup \emptyset = A$ but $\{A, B\} \ne \{A \cup B\}$ so $\{A\} = \{A \cup \emptyset\} \ne \{A, \emptyset\}$.

$\{A,B\}$ is a set with two things in it. Those two things are two sets.  $A \cup B$ is one set; a combined set-- all the elements of A and B are dumped out, mixed together and packed up into a new set.  So $\{A\cup B\}$ is a set with only one thing int it.  That one thing is one set.  So $\{A,B\} \ne \{A \cup B\}$.